# Kernel panic - Macbook pro 15" early 2011

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

I have problem with "Your computer restarted because of a problem" loop. Sometimes my Mac doesn't crash all day, but sometimes it crashes 5-10 times at day. Thank you for every advice. Kernel panic log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       7E28CD64-5454-660E-6A00-2262744C1355

Tue Aug 18 15:30:21 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa8e964a1): "AGC GPU REGISTER RESTORE FAILED : rdar://7254528, VendorID invalid"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.10.22/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/AGCPowerManagement.cpp:1159
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8169aabdb0 : 0xffffff802672bda1 
0xffffff8169aabe30 : 0xffffff7fa8e964a1 
0xffffff8169aabe70 : 0xffffff7fa8e992f2 
0xffffff8169aabea0 : 0xffffff8026cda403 
0xffffff8169aabf00 : 0xffffff802675e759 
0xffffff8169aabfb0 : 0xffffff80268125b7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.10.22)[26F693CB-BFE8-33FA-9D1F-3F66FC016768]@0xffffff7fa8e8b000->0xffffff7fa8e9efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.10.22)[61967104-88AF-3605-82F5-A480A2800A78]@0xffffff7fa8e78000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7fa71a9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7fa6f24000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7fa78c2000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[65E3187E-949B-36E9-BA33-1B13ABB0581A]@0xffffff7fa8e86000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000026400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8026600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8026500000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 856552754156
last loaded kext at 29166169161: com.disc-soft.DAEMONTools.VirtualSCSIBus   1.0.2 (addr 0xffffff7fa9cac000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 122843109001: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7fa760c000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.disc-soft.DAEMONTools.VirtualSCSIBus    1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.12
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.3.2
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2 GHz, 10 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M, AMD Radeon HD 6490M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x43543130323436344246313333392E433136
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 18 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB, 250,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545050B9A302, 500,11 GB
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Comment: Try this to make sure its not a hardware issue. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same problem, with exactly the same error message, on the same model of Macbook.

Initially I thought that the AMD discrete graphics was damaged; this is a frequent issue with those machines.
However, I found out that if I force the Mac to use **only** the AMD discrete graphics, then the problem does not occur anymore. It might be, therefore, an issue with the integrated Intel HD 3000 graphics; perhaps a software issue after the upgrade to El Capitan 10.11.4

Waiting for Apple to fix the software, I suggest the following remedy

- In **System Preferences -> Energy Saver**
- Uncheck the **Automatic Graphics Switching** option.

  This will force the Mac to use the AMD graphics. I'd love to know if this solves your problem.

  If this does not work for you, or even leads to more frequent panics, then the AMD discrete GPU might be damaged. In this case, please note that Apple has active a free repair programme for 2011 Mac having this specific issue, see

http://www.macrumors.com/2016/02/19/apple-extends-mbp-video-repair-program/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel extensions in backtrace (look in your dump) point to (possibly) a graphics issue. It could be a damaged driver or you could be having problems with the graphics hardware itself.

The fact that it happens intermittently may point to the latter but diagnosing this long distance... well no guarantees.

Pitr Pitucha left a comment that leads (just) to a link. A link to apple hardware diagnostics. Tho a bit terse his recommendation is sound as the Diagnostics may (eventually) point to where the problem is.

I would run it once a day for a week when you have time to do so and see if you can catch it in action.

Failing that, reinstalling the O/S (and then the updates) might be a good idea as that will overwrite any possibly corrupted drivers or config files. Do back up first tho...